# Which select statement is suitable for the below SQLServer View?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the **total number of trips** a meter has undergone based on a set of records.

```
-- MeterRecord Table
Id   IVoltage  ICurrent
--------------------
1     340       0 <<<-- (Trip is zero at this point)
2     288       1
3     312       2
4     236       1
5     343       0 <<<-- (Trip is one at this point)
6     342       0
7     264       1
8     269       0 <<<-- (Trip is two at this point)
```

Trip is incremented by one only when 'ICurrent' value returns back to zero from a previous non-zero state.

What i have tried using Count function:

```
Select SUM(IVoltage) as Sum_Voltage, COUNT(case when ICurrent = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Trips
```

This returns

```
Sum_Voltage  Trips
---------------------
45766          8
```

What i am trying to achieve based on the table above

```
--MeterRecord View
Sum_Voltage  Trips
---------------------
   45766          2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LAG to determine if you have a trip:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #meterRecord
CREATE TABLE #meterRecord 
(
Id INT,
IVoltage INT,
ICurrent INT
);

INSERT INTO #meterRecord
VALUES
(1,340,0), 
(2,288,1),
(3,312,2),
(4,236,1),
(5,343,0), 
(6,342,0),
(7,264,1),
(8,269,0);

WITH cte AS 
(
 SELECT IVoltage,
    CASE WHEN ICurrent = 0 AND LAG(ICurrent,1) OVER(ORDER BY Id) != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END isTrip
 FROM #meterRecord
)
SELECT SUM(cte.IVoltage) AS Sum_Voltage,
SUM(isTrip) AS Trips
FROM cte
```